# 'MalformedURLException' while parsing an XML file using DocumentBuilder

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to parse an xml file using 'DocumentBuilder' and got following error.

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/application_1_2.dtd>
```

First part of my xml file is like this (XML file cannot be changed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.2//EN' '<http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/application_1_2.dtd>'>
<application>
<display-name>Black hole</display-name>
<description>Black hole service framework</description>
<module>
  <ejb>StructureService.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
  <ejb>ResourceService.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
  <ejb>DatumServiceInternal.jar</ejb>
</module>
```

Here, How I tried to parse the XML file

```
File xml = new File(path);

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(xml);

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

return db.parse(inputStream , "UTF-8");
```

I tried to do it different ways, but I got above error constantly. Please help me to find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the entity resolver if you can't change the dtd url in xml, below I modified your earlier code.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();        
    EntityResolver er = new EntityResolver() {            
        @Override
        public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
                throws SAXException, IOException {
            System.out.println(publicId);
            System.out.println(systemId);
             if (systemId.startsWith("<") && systemId.endsWith(">")) {
                    return new InputSource(systemId.substring(1,systemId.length()-1));
            }
            return null;
        }
    };        
    db.setEntityResolver(er);
    db.parse(inputStream , "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused within this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.2//EN' '<http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/application_1_2.dtd>'>
```

Remove the < > brackets within the following part of the doctype:

```
'<http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/application_1_2.dtd>'
```

It should work now. I tried it on my own with your xml content and didn't have any exceptions. 
Here you have my version of your xml content as a whole:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.2//EN' 'http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/application_1_2.dtd'>
<application>
<display-name>Black hole</display-name>
<description>Black hole service framework</description>
<module>
  <ejb>StructureService.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
  <ejb>ResourceService.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
  <ejb>DatumServiceInternal.jar</ejb>
</module>
</application>
```

Hope it helps you. Oh and you can also pass your File object directly to the parse() function without generating a FileInputStream

Comment: Unfortunately, It's impossible to change the xml file.

Comment: Also I directly passed my file as well and there was no change

Comment: Where do you get the .xml file from? Is it automatically generated?

Comment: It is existing file within the project. However, the problem is solved by Naveen. Thanks for the help.